# Asp.net MVC passed values to modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a table from my view and it loads data from my Mysql db and once you click the button update in the table it will have a pop-up which supposedly load the details from my table and my problem is it is not getting the correct value, every time that I will clicked any on my row table it will have the same value.

Here is my View:

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>OP</th>
        <th>OP Desc</th>                
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.op</td>
            <td>@item.op_desc</td>
            <td>                            

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Update</button>

                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle"><b>Update selected values:</b></h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                    <dt>
                                        OP:
                                    </dt>
                                    <dd>
                                        @item.op
                                    </dd>
                                    <dt>
                                        OP Desc:
                                    </dt>
                                    <dd>
                                        @item.op_desc                                               
                                </dl>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

so rather than displaying on my current tab I decided to pass it to modal to make it as pop-up

Comment: you should pass id through button , when click

Comment: I already thinking of that, do have initial idea that I can start up using this code?

Comment: Do you want to load data from controller to view ? or pass exact row to controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is all of your buttons are pointing to the same modal:

```
data-target="#exampleModalCenter"
```

and all of your modals have the same id (which is not a valid HTML):

```
id="exampleModalCenter"
```

To fix the problem, you need to give each modal a unique id, something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

   <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@Model.UseSomeUniqueProperty" // other attributes...
   <div id="@Model.UseSomeUniqueProperty" class="modal fade" // other attributes

   // rest of your code...
```